# How to access midi percussion on delphi?

Tags: delphi, midi, channel

I know how to play the 128 sounds form midi instruments, what I am needing is how to access the midi percussion.

Comment: Before everyone downvotes, I believe this question is very valid. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Percussion.

Comment: Isn't percussion usually just one (or more) of the instrument presets, representing a drum kit, with each drum, cymbal, and so on, mapped to its own keyboard key?

Comment: You play percussion by sending notes to percussion channel, in the same way as to other channels. What exactly is the problem? What does your code look like sofar?

Comment: 500-InternalServerError: I believe that is not the case. Look at the Wikipedia question. Tom: I believe Jack does not know how to change the channel.

Comment: Yes, Andreas is right! Thanks, Andreas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Percussion), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [MIDI.org](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php), I found out how to use the percussion 'instruments'. (That is, I found out how to set the channel.) Try the following code. It is totally awesome.

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, MMSystem;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

type
  TMIDIInstrument = (midiAcousticGrandPiano, midiBrightAcousticPiano,
                     midiElectricGrandPiano, midiHonkyTonkPiano,
                     midiRhodesPiano, midiChorusedPiano, midiHarpsichord,
                     midiClavinet, midiCelesta, midiGlockenspiel,
                     midiMusicBox, midiVibraphone, midiMarimba, midiXylophone,
                     midiTubularBells, midiDulcimer, midiHammondOrgan,
                     midiPercussiveOrgan, midiRockOrgan, midiChurchOrgan,
                     midiReedOrgan, midiAccordion, midiHarmonica,
                     midiTangoAccordion, midiAcousticGuitarNylon,
                     midiAcousticGuitarSteel, midiElectricGuitarJazz,
                     midiElectricGuitarClean, midiElectricGuitarMuted,
                     midiOverdrivenGuitar, midiDistortionGuitar,
                     midiGuitarHarmonics, midiAcousticBass, midiElectricBassFinger,
                     midiElectricBassPick, midiFretlessBass, midiSlapBass1,
                     midiSlapBass2, midiSynthBass1, midiSynthBass2, midiViolin,
                     midiViola, midiCello, midiContrabass, midiTremoloStrings,
                     midiPizzicatoStrings, midiOrchestralHarp, midiTimpani,
                     midiStringEnsemble1, midiStringEnsemble2, midiSynthStrings1,
                     midiSynthStrings2, midiChoirAahs, midiVoiceOohs,
                     midiSynthVoice, midiOrchestraHit, midiTrumpet, midiTrombone,
                     midiTuba, midiMutedTrumpet, midiFrenchHorn, midiBrassSection,
                     midiSynthBrass1, midiSynthBrass2, midiSopranoSax, midiAltoSax,
                     midiTenorSax, midiBaritoneSax, midiOboe, midiEnglishHorn,
                     midiBassoon, midiClarinet, midiPiccolo, midiFlute,
                     midiRecorder, midiPanFlute, midiBottleBlow, midiShakuhachi,
                     midiWhistle, midiOcarina, midiLead1Square,
                     midiLead2Sawtooth, midiLead3CalliopeLead, midiLead4ChiffLead,
                     midiLead5Charang, midiLead6Voice, midiLead7Fifths,
                     midiLead8BrassLead, midiPad1NewAge, midiPad2Warm,
                     midiPad3Polysynth, midiPad4Choir, midiPad5Bowed,
                     midiPad6Metallic, midiPad7Halo, midiPad8Sweep, midiFX1Rain,
                     midiFX2Soundtrack, midiFX3Crystal, midiFX4Atmosphere, midiFX5Brightness, midiFX6Goblins,
                     midiFX7Echoes, midiFX8SciFi, midiSitar, midiBanjo, midiShamisen,
                     midiKoto, midiKalimba, midiBagpipe, midiFiddle,
                     midiShanai, midiTinkleBelll, midiAgogo, midiSteelDrums,
                     midiWoodblock, midiTaikoDrum, midiMelodicTom, midiSynthDrum,
                     midiReverseCymbal, midiGuitarFretNoise, midiBreathNoise,
                     midiSeashore, midiBirdTweet, midiTelephoneRing,
                     midiHelicopter, midiApplause, midiGunshot);

const
  MIDI_NOTE_ON = $90;
  MIDI_NOTE_OFF = $80;
  MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT = $C0;
  MIDI_DEVICE = 0;
  MIDI_VEL = 108;
  MIDI_PERCUSSION_CHANNEL = 9;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  mo: HMIDIOUT;

function MIDIEncodeMessage(Channel, Msg, Param1, Param2: integer): integer;
begin
  result := Channel or Msg + (Param1 shl 8) + (Param2 shl 16);
end;

procedure SetCurrentInstrument(CurrentInstrument: TMIDIInstrument);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(0, MIDI_CHANGE_INSTRUMENT, ord(CurrentInstrument), 0));
end;

procedure NoteOn(Channel, NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(Channel, MIDI_NOTE_ON, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure NoteOff(Channel, NewNote, NewIntensity: byte);
begin
  midiOutShortMsg(mo, MIDIEncodeMessage(Channel, MIDI_NOTE_OFF, NewNote, NewIntensity));
end;

procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  midiOutOpen(@mo, 0, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);
  midiOutSetVolume(mo, $FFFFFFFF);

  // Normal MIDI
  SetCurrentInstrument(midiChurchOrgan);
  NoteOn(0, 20, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOn(0, 50, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOn(0, 80, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOn(0, 110, 127);
  sleep(1000);
  NoteOff(0, 110, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOff(0, 80, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOff(0, 50, 127);
  sleep(200);
  NoteOff(0, 20, 127);

  SetCurrentInstrument(midiAcousticGuitarNylon);
  NoteOn(0, 100, 127);
  NoteOn(0, 50, 127);

  sleep(1000);

  // Percussion
  for i := 0 to 127 do
  begin
    NoteOn(MIDI_PERCUSSION_CHANNEL, i, 127);
    sleep(100);
  end;

end;

end.
```

As you can see, you only need to include the channel into the MIDI message. The percussion channel is 9 (the 10th channel). (All other channels are 'normal' channels; see the Wikipedia article.)

Comment: Now you should read also [`this`](http://www.wikihow.com/Contact-Record-Labels). Step 1 you can skip :)

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Perfect, Andreas!!! You´re a blessed man!

Comment: @JackLima It seems Andreas went through a lot of work to answer this for you. You should show your appreciation by accepting this answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of it).

Answer (score 1):

The MIDI standard itself does not define any instruments or percussion sounds.

The General MIDI specification defines 128 instruments, and 47 percussion sounds.
All channels except channel 9 (counting from zero) play instruments, channel 9 plays percussion sounds, with different note numbers resulting in different sounds.

Other specifications (General MIDI 2, GS, XG etc.) define more sounds, and have mechanisms to select which channel(s) to use for percussion sounds.